# Extract specific strings from text file

Tags: notepad++, regex

From this file:

```
xxxxxxx; foo("this should be extracted 1"); bar("this should not be extracted"); yyyyyyy

zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz foo("this should be extracted 2") uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
```

I want to get this:

```
this should be extracted 1

this should be extracted 2
```

I only managed to select the strings I want to extract using this regex: `(?<=foo\(")(.*?)(?="\))`. But I can't find a way to extract it or to delete all the unmarked text.

I put some `x, y, z` and `u` characters in the example just to show that in this file there are a lot of other things in the same line

Could somebody help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `^(?:(?!foo\(\").)*$` to delete all lines not containing `foo("`

Then `^\r\n` to remove empty lines

And then use `^.*foo\(\"(.*?)\"\).*` to replace all with `\1`

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^|\G).*?foo\("(.+?)"\)(?:(?!\bfoo\().)*`
- Replace with: `$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:^|\G)            # beginning of line OR restart from last match position
.*?                 # 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
foo\("              # literally
(.+?)               # group 1, 1 or more any character but newline not greedy, what to be extracted
"\)
(?:(?!\foo\().)*    # Tempered greedy token, make sure we haven't "foo" after
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1         # content of group 1, what to be extracted
```

**Result for given example:**

```
this should be extracted 1

this should be extracted 2
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]